# I have 2 problems with security() , both of them are related to lower time frames

Tags: pine-script

people. I would appreciate some help. Here is my code:

```
//@version=4
study(title="my trading set up",overlay=true)
otherTf=input(title="Other time frame",type=input.resolution,defval="D")
tfHigh=security(syminfo.tickerid,otherTf,pivothigh(high,2,2))
tfLow=security(syminfo.tickerid,otherTf,pivotlow(low,2,2))
plot(tfHigh,color=color.green,style=plot.style_circles,linewidth=5, offset=-2)
plot(tfLow,color=color.red,style=plot.style_circles,linewidth=5,offset=-2)
```

I have 2 problems:

1)  On a daily time frame, it works just fine. However, on a lower time frame, the `tfHigh` and `tfLow` values are shown like the plot function was set without `offset` argument.

2) On the lower time frame, the `tfHigh` and `tfLow` values are shown between two-time frames. Ex. the `tfHigh` happened on 25th. On the lower time frame that value will be shown between 25th and 26th. I've tried with changing the time of the exchange, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the offset of -2 you are plotting with is only good for the 1D TF where the pivots are detected. At TFs < 1d, your challenge will be to:

1. Figure out the actual bar corresponding to that pivot value, which will occur at a variable offset.
2. Go back a variable number of bars to actually plot.

You can solve problem 2 pretty easily by using [line drawings](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Drawings.html) rather than plots.

Solving problem 1 is more complex because:

1. The dilation of the higher TF onto the current chart's bars will vary with its resolution. E.g., on a 24/7 market, the 1H dilation of your 1D HTF should contain 24 bars.
2. The actual number of bars in the dilation often does not correspond to its theoretical value because of irregular hours, holidays, shutdowns, irregularities in the feed, etc.
3. The pivot price you detected at the higher TF sometimes does not exist on the dilation's bars.

While you could calculate approximations of the offset where the pivot should be situated using functions like `f_avgDilationOf(_res)` or `f_theoreticalDilationOf(_res)` from our [MTF Selection Framework](https://www.tradingview.com/script/90mqACUV-MTF-Selection-Framework-PineCoders-FAQ/), the most robust way is to use a `for` loop, as is done in the [Pivots MTF](https://www.tradingview.com/script/VYzEUnYB-Pivots-MTF-LucF/) indicator, where an educated guess limits the range of how far the loop looks back so it doesn't unduly slow things down, and provision is made so the lookback doesn't fail when an exact value is not found.